# MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() returns wrong value using V8

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I am working on a gmail addon using google apps scripts (V8) and I have noticied that [MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getRemainingDailyQuota()) returns a random value (between two values).

```js
const remainingQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
```

Switching to DEPRECATED_ES5 it works fine, but I would like to continue working with V8. Is there any way to fix it?

My testflow is:
1) Create completely new project from scratch (so there is no other code to influence it's behaviour).
2) Create a test function to log MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota().
3) Run this function in debug several times with ES5 and V8.

Result is: ES5 always right, V8 half of times gives me a wrong value. I also tried in incognito mode, so I have only one account logged in, but nothing changes.

PS: I am logged into two accounts on chrome.

Comment: Does it work for you as intended when running from the Script Editor V8 directly (without the Add-on)? did you upgrade or Gmail Addon to a [G-Suite Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/upgrade-addons#step_3_update_your_add-ons_manifest)?

Comment: I have the same problem running it within script editor (in debug). Yes, it's a G Suite addon.

Comment: I tested it in Apps Script editor and it works correctly for me... Maybe there are other parts of your code that interfere with the result? I assume you updated your Apps Script editor to v8?

Comment: My testflow is: 1) create completely new project from scratch (so there is no other code to influence it's behaviour). 2) Create a test function to log MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota(). 3) Run this function in debug several times with ES5 and V8. Result is: ES5 always right, V8 half of times gives me a wrong value. I also tried in incognito mode, so I have only one account logged in, but nothing changes.

Comment: What exactly does your test function look like?

Comment: `
function myFunction() {
  var remainingQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  console.log(remainingQuota);
}
`

Comment: This always gives me a quota of 1500 (as expected). I really do not understand why it does not work for you.

Comment: Neither I do, that's why I asked it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.
When I execute this function by using trigger per 1 minute with V8, The Remains show random numbers.

```
function MailSendAndQuota() {
  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Remaining email quota: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
  
  var mailAddress = "abc@abc.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress,"TestSubject","Remains:" + emailQuotaRemaining);
}
```

Comment: Your contribution fits more into a comment, as you don't provide any answer here.